# Print array that was set in another function with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

As you can see in the code below I tried to print an array that I created in a different function. The output was totally different numbers compares to what I  expected: numbers between 0 - 20 were set but I got some negative values.

So my question is why is this happening? And how to fix it if it even possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LEN 10
int* creatingArray();
void printingArray(int* array);
int main(void)
{
    int* pointer_array = creatingArray();
    printingArray(pointer_array);
    getchar();  
    return 0;
}
int* creatingArray()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int array[LEN] = { 0 };
    int* i = 0;
    for (i = array; i < array + LEN; i++)
    {
        *i = rand() % 20;
    }
    return array;
}
void printingArray(int* array)
{
    int* i = 0;
    for (i = array; i < array + LEN; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", *i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to this code:

```
int* creatingArray()
{
    // stuff
    int array[LEN] = { 0 };
    // more stuff
    return array;
}
```

`array` is a local variable, so it gets destroyed when the function returns. You then have a pointer to a destroyed variable. The space where it was will (most likely) continue to hold the data you put there - until the memory gets reused for something else and overwritten.

> and how to fix it if it eve/n possible?

Several options:

1. Make `array` a `static` variable. Then it will not be destroyed when the function returns. (This also means that every time you call `creatingArray` it will use the same `array`, instead of a new one)
2. Make `array` global.
3. Move `array` to `main`, and pass a pointer to it *into* `creatingArray`, instead of having `creatingArray` return one. Then, since it's a local variable in `main`, it will only be destroyed when `main` returns.
4. Use `malloc` to allocate some space that will not be cleaned up automatically when the function returns.